# Unable to send email to domain hosted on google apps

Tags: email, g-suite

I support a domain for a sports club (fingaltri.ie) and use Google Apps for email.  This has been working fine until recently when all mail to either individual accounts or groups started getting bounced.  Even sending mail within our Google account gets bounced (see bounce response below).

all of the MX records look correct and I have added an SPF entry:

> v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

and the domain isn't blacklisted (according to MXtools.com).

Two other DNS related things that may be significant:

1. My ISP has included it's own MX record although the first google one seems to take priority
2. My ISP also includes its own SPF record: v=spf1 a mx

I am unable to delete either of these records using my control panel.  Could either of these be the cause of the problem?

Any help appreciated.

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
> XXXXXX@fingaltri.ie
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: 
>   Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 553 553 sorry, that address is not in my list of allowed recipients; no valid cert for gatewaying (#5.7.1) (state 14).
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Received: by 10.236.136.38 with SMTP id v26mr15360391yhi.69.1322787413227;
>   Thu, 01 Dec 2011 16:56:53 -0800 (PST)
>   Received: by 10.146.197.20 with HTTP; Thu, 1 Dec 2011 16:56:53 -0800 (PST)
>   X-Originating-IP: [206.169.118.46]
>   Date: Thu, 1 Dec 2011 16:56:53 -0800
>   Message-ID: 
>   Subject: test
>   From: "XXXXXX" 
>   To: "XXXXXX" 
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=20cf303bfe28e0f78404b31171b6

Comment: Are you able to receive mail (i.e. the only 'bounces' you are seeing are when sending from that domain)? Just for my own due diligence, I checked mxtoolbox.com, and didn't see much wrong for that domain (fingaltri.ie). What I DID find, when I examined the MX records was this: 
10 smtp1r.cp.blacknight.com 81.17.254.9 60 min

(which you mentioned is a record that your host includs)

All of the other entries are pointed to Google's servers, and while you have another MX entry in there set at a level preference of 10, my guess is this is throwing things off. Not sure though...

Comment: David, that's what I was thinking but was not sure.  I've disabled the offending records and will check again once the changes filter through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 553 553 error is not from google.
The problem comes from the mx records

```
dig fingaltri.ie mx

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      10 aspmx.l.google.com.
***fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      10 smtp1r.cp.blacknight.com***.
fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
fingaltri.ie.           3600    IN      MX      40 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

You have to remove  10 smtp1r.cp.blacknight.com. ,
your ISP screwed your settings.

Comment: And if you can't change it, then switch the ISP.

Comment: I got the ISP to remove the records and now mails are working ok.